# Looking for nice RoR way to correctly validate a state of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model and a column of this model represents a state . It's numeric value and it could be 1,2,3.

I have two concerns:

a) Based on the business logic, the state can only go from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. It can't go back from higher numbers to lower number and it can't just from 1 to 3 in one step.

b) I don't want to expose these numbers to controllers (don't like magical numbers flying around).

I did following

- I created methods like stateX?, stateY?, stateZ? to allow controllers check current state.
  This helps me with concern b).
- I created methods setStateX, setStateY, stateZ and raise in them, if a controller does unacceptable switch of state. This helps me with concern a) and b).

However, I feel that's more Java/C++ way (which is my background) - 6 methods to do one thing.

Is there any better way to accomplish this in RoR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still the best way to do it (my Rails is a little rusty) but there is a gem called [acts_as_state_machine](https://github.com/omghax/acts_as_state_machine) which I think will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure that I will use exactly this gem, but using a state machine gem is really great idea.

Comment: Yeah I haven't used Rails in a while so I don't know what the latest state machine gem is, but `acts_as_state_machine` was the one I used and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_state


  private

  def check_state
    if state_changed?
      if state_was == 1 && state != 2
        self.errors.add(:state, "some message")
      elsif state_was == 2 && state != 3
        self.errors.add(:state, "some message")
      else
        self.errors.add(:state, "some message")
      end
    end
  end

end
```